# Div side by side not working

Tags: html, css

I have two divs side by side in a control (RadRotator).

```
<div class="title_link_Wrapper">
 <div class="title">
  <span><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("title").ToString())%></span>
 </div>
 <div class="link">
  <span><a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString()%>">Link</a></span>
 </div>
</div>


.title_link_Wrapper {
    width:550px;
}

.title{
   
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-left:6px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:6px;
}
.link {
    margin-top:6px;
}
```

It is working in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velocirapto/kTuL2/)

But is not working in the control:

[image]

Any hint?

Comment: Inspect with debugger to see what styles are applied to figure out the issue. With what you have provided, there is no way to tell what's causing this. If you put a link down, then people can at least go to the apge and inspect

Comment: add the rendered html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kTuL2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table;`(*parent div*) and `display:table-cell;`(*children div*) which gives the same output and works most of the times:

**CSS**

```
.title_link_Wrapper {
    width:550px;
    display:table;
}

.title{
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-left:6px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:6px;
}
.link {
    display:table-cell;
    min-width:60px;
    margin-top:6px;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jP8sT/)

Comment: Thats a good one! Thanks Zword, your suggestion solved the problem.

Comment: @FeliceM Alwys glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot add `float:left;` to the div with class link.

Comment: Is there live version, not fiddle? I would like to see it with debugger.

Comment: What do you mean a live version?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this :

```
 <div class="title_link_Wrapper">
   <div class="title">LeftLeft
    <span class="link">right</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.title_link_Wrapper {
    width:550px;
}

.title{

    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-left:6px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:6px;
}
.link {
    margin-top:6px;
    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kTuL2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Div by default is Display: Block, which causes an element to be alone on that line.
you will want to force your divs to be Display: Inline

```
.title{

    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-left:6px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:6px;
    display: inline; /* add this */
}
.link {
    margin-top:6px;
    display: inline; /* add this */
    float: right; /* add this */
}
```

you may even want to wrap them in a div set to block.
Another thing that may happen is there is no specific width on .link, so if that gets wider than 20% you will spill over into the next row again, since you .title is set to 80%